# How to get Google map polygon vertex point draw/pin event?

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I want to allow a user to draw polygon inside the polygon. I can get lat/long using constainsLocation function (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) But when user draws a polygon I want to detect that the point/vertex drawn by user is inside the polygon. So there any event to detect click/draw event when user is drawing polygon?

```js
 
var map; // Global declaration of the map
   var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Global declaration of the infowindow
   var lat_longs = new Array();
   var markers = new Array();
   var drawingManager;
   function initialize() {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.9403762, -74.1318096);
    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 13,
     center: myLatlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
       position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
     drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
    },
      polygonOptions: {
       editable: true
      }
   });
   drawingManager.setMap(map);
   
   google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event) {
    var newShape = event.overlay;
    newShape.type = event.type;
   });

            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event){
                overlayClickListener(event.overlay);
                $('#vertices').val(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
            });
        }
function overlayClickListener(overlay) {
    alert('hello');
    google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, "mouseup", function(event){
        $('#vertices').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
        
    });
}
 initialize();

$(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        //iterate polygon vertices?
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing&dummy=.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:450px;"></div>
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="map_form">
    <input type="text" name="vertices" value="" id="vertices"  />
    <input type="button" name="save" value="Save!" id="save"  />
</form>
```

When user draws first polygon than user should not be able to draw another polygon outside it. Is there any event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Drawing Manager to make the area of the Google Maps outside the Polygon as non-editable.

Once the user draw a polygon (when you see that the user has reached the same point/vertex from where he started) call this function to make rest of the area of Google Map as non-editable.

```
$('#showRes').click(function(){
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    drawingManager.setOptions({ 
        polygonOptions: {
            paths: pathArr,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            editable: false,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            geodesic: true,
            suppressUndo: true
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that Helps!!